# Google Map places autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places, google-maps-autocomplete

I wanted to implement AutocompleteFragment (google places) but when I click to search view in a fragment, the fragment disappears (fell down). 
Google Maps and Places API work and in console I see error:

> places.PlacesService.AutocompleteWidget: 100

I can't find what it could mean. 
I tried to use advices in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416817/how-to-implement-placeautocompletefragment-and-placeautocompleteactivity-to-get) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392894/placeautocompletefragment-disappears-on-click) answers, but it didn't work.

My build.gradle implementations:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

Permissions and meta-data in Android.manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="it.mappe.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="there_is_my_api_key"/>
```

In activity layout I have this XML:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;
GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    createMapView();
}

private void createMapView() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
            .build();

    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place place) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status + ", status code " + status.getStatusCode());
        }
    });
}
```

And when I tap searchview in fragment I see this in LogCat:

> An error occurred: Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}, status code 13

And [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes) give me a beutiful explaination of "status code 13":

> The operation failed with no more detailed information.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error "error 13" ,and I asked that question in stackoverflow .

Although I did not get any answer but I got a comment from the person who works at Google maps. He said its a bug from googles side
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462846/i-get-error-13-in-place-auto-complete-fragment) to my question

I looked  for answers try them :

api key library should consist places api for android,web and maps 
multidex support should be there

Comment: I made the new project and still have the same error. I can't understand your last phrase, cat you explain, please?

Comment: I have made a demo on Autocompletefragment  .Wait i'll post it on github and send you  a link . That code works for me .Lets see if it works for you

Comment: Thank you for your demo, it was very helpful, because it doesn't work with my API :) I make a new Google account and new payment account and now it works with new accounts, thank you!

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

get google API key from [Google console](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiay6ie2fTeAhXDXn0KHXDPAGwQFjAAegQIDhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw1GxwHR1WZnDu0xsR-djCrv) and add in meta data

It would look something like : *AIsddsfdsf-FAdsdsf6755fgfgdd3w*

[Official Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key) How to generate Map API Key

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="there_is_my_api_key"/>
```

Comment: I have my API key there, change that line only for this post. Google console shows positive requests to MapsSDK, but all requests to PlacesSDK have this error in console: places.PlacesService.AutocompleteWidget: 100